# Function pointer to an instance member

Tags: c++, stl, function-pointers

I need to map some state to a particular member function of a class, for (a very cut down) example:

```
class Z {
   _a_ptr_to_some_member _p;

   void UpdateGuiForStopState(State s) {
      // do something with state
   }

   Z() {
      // setup _p to point to UpdateGuiForStopState
   }

   void StateComesInHere(State s) {
      if(s.id == STOP_ID) { // eventually use lookup
         _p(s);
      }
   }
}
```

Using just the STL (can't use third party stuff like boost), What is the type of _a_ptr_to_some_member and how do I bind the method UpdateGuiForStopState to it?

Presumably I use the stl mem_xxx stuff but can't work out how.

And yes I can do this a hundred and one other different ways, but I want to work out if this way is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using STL's `bind1st` and `mem_fun`:

```
class Z3 {
   typedef std::mem_fun1_t<void,Z3,State> _a_ptr_to_some_member_raw;
   typedef std::binder1st<_a_ptr_to_some_member_raw> _a_ptr_to_some_member;
   _a_ptr_to_some_member _p;

   void UpdateGuiForStopState(State s) {
      // do something with state
   }

   Z3() : _p(std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(&Z3::UpdateGuiForStopState), this))
   {
   }

   void StateComesInHere(State s) {
      if(s.id == STOP_ID) { // eventually use lookup
         _p(s);
      }
   }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using just raw pointers to members:

```
typedef void (Z::*_a_ptr_to_some_member)(State s);
_a_ptr_to_some_member _p;
...
_p = &Z::UpdateGuiForStopState;
...
(this->*_p)(s);
```

That's a bit old school these days, and the syntax is a bit hairy, but it should work. (Caveat: I haven't tried it.)

The first bit defines the correct type of pointer to a member function and declares a member variable of that type.

The second bit initialises _p to point to the correct function (you can't shorten this, that's the required syntax).

The third bit calls the member function pointed to by _p; to do that you have to supply an instance of Z - in this case the one pointed to by this. I think the extra parenthese are needed; the operator precedence is a bit weird.

TBH I'd probably use bind (from boost, tr1, or C++11) for this; it's very slightly slower, but easier and more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `std::function`, or, `boost::function` if you don't have C++0x/TR1 support. The easiest way to use them would be using `boost::bind` or `std::bind`, I wouldn't use the Standard's `bind1st` and such mess when `boost::bind` is much better and easier.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example (see http://ideone.com/VEmRZ):

```
#include <iostream>

typedef enum { s0, s1, s2 } State ;

class Z {
public:
  void f0 (State s) { std::cout << "f0" << std::endl ; }
  void f1 (State s) { std::cout << "f1" << std::endl ; }
} ;

typedef void (Z::*_a_ptr_to_some_member)(State s);

int main()
  {
  Z z ;
  _a_ptr_to_some_member _p = &Z::f0 ;
  (z.*_p)(s0) ;
  _p = &Z::f1 ;
  (z.*_p)(s2) ;
  }
```